# failing "Private Test Cases" in pyschools

Tags: python

I used the following script to try to answer [this](http://www.pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s2-q11) question:

```
def isEquilateral(x, y, z): 
    if x<0 or y <0 or z<0:
        return False
    elif x==y==z:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It returned `Private Test Cases`, I don't know if this is a software bug, or my code really have some problem. Can anyone help? Thanks.

#### update 01

Question as below:
Write a function isEquilateral(x, y, z) that accepts the 3 sides of a triangle as arguments. The program should return True if it is an equilateral triangle.

Examples

```
>>> isEquilateral(2, 4, 3)
False
>>> isEquilateral(3, 3, 3)
True
>>> isEquilateral(-3, -3, -3)
False
```

Comment: I suggest you post the question. It seems like you have to register to see the question.

Comment: Without seeing the question, the only thing that sticks out is the case where `x, y, z = 0, 0, 0` will return `True` which may not be the goal.

Comment: @D.Shawley thanks, that's the reason, silly me...

Comment: This function could be written more simply as `isEquilateral = lambda x,y,z: x>0 and x==y==z`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I'm not impressed with their feedback system, the problem is you return True when x, y, z == 0.  A simpler solution:

```
def isEquilateral(x, y, z):
    if x == y == z and x > 0:
        return True
    return False
```

And an even simpler solution, which shows off the beauty of Python (thanks, F.J!) using even more [chained comparisons](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

```
def isEquilateral(x, y, z):
    return x == y == z > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
def isEquilateral(x, y, z): 
    if (x == y or x == z) and x > 0:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Is this solution correct? Consider the triangle with side lengths 1, 1, and 2. This is not an equilateral triangle. Yet `x = 1; y = 1; z = 2; (x == y or x == z) and x > 0`evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
def isEquilateral(x, y, z): 
    a = [x,y,z]
    for e in a:
        if e> 0:
            if x==y==z:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: If you can, please comment on what this solution adds to the accepted answer.

Comment: An equilateral triangle can't have a side length of less than 0. Therefore, instead of only checking if the first side,x, as others did here, I returned the function's arguments to a list and iterative over each element in the list using a for a loop. This checks for all sides if they are greater than 0.

Comment: If all of the sides have the same length `x==y==z` and any one of the sides has a length greater than zero, then all of the sides have a length greater than zero. If this is true, then we only need to check the length of any one side. So we check the side labeled x. If x>0 and x==y then y>0. if x>0 and x==z then z>0. Of course we instead could have checked y>0 or z>0, but there's no need to check all three sides. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, I now clearly understand the reason behind not checking all the variables. Thanks for this clarification!